# Does PostgreSQL push autoincrement id based on UPDATE record which was inserted with explicit PK declaration?

Tags: c#, postgresql, auto-increment

Explicit PK declaration in inserts: can I push autoincrement value by update those records?

The question besically says it all. I have seed data with ID (PK) explicitly declared so Postgres doesn't realise that I already have e.g. id 1 and 2. Can I update those entries changing e.g. name property to make Postgres realise id 1 and 2 are already in the table and make it start from 3? If not, what's other good way to do this but only through .net core C# code with code-first approach with migrations?

**UPDATE**
After trying out some things, I decided to resign from explicitly id declarations in seed, it was easier after all to change that and identify records other way than by ids which made Postgres instantly work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's valid to force a value to a key auto-generated with a sequence, this will create more issues than it will solve.

Solution 1, ask the database to tell you the id it used:
`INSERT INTO Mytable(<place field list, excluding id>) VALUES (<place field values>) RETURNING id`

That way, you get to know what id was used.

Solution 2 (closer to what you want but that I do not really recommend), force the sequence to take a new value:
`SELECT setval('<your sequence name>', 3, true);`

Comment: I don't wanna ask db anything. I have seed method that always inserts 2 records with id 1 and 2. These inserts are the only ones with explicitly set ids instead of using autoinc. Overall it's mssql as main and it realises id incrementing even when ids are explicitly declared. Postgres is additional db. I also don't want to use any straight SQL queries but get it done with EF Core. The solution has to work on each db, I just change dbProvider in Api and that has to be enough. Every other inserts have to be done with autoinc ids, only seed has to explicitly declare them.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear; I assume that you want to advance the current value of an autoincremented column to avoid collisions with already inserted values.

For that, find out which sequence is backing the autoincrement column. The `psql` command `\d` will be helpful.

Then advance the current value with something like

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name RESTART 123456;
```

Comment: There's no backing or I don't know what you mean. It's just seed inserting id (pk) explicitly that do not push autoincremented value to 3, it stays at 1. That's clear and I need postgres to realise that I do this and insert another records with proper id values (which in this example means start id = 3 beacuse 1 and 2 are already there).